# How to write function that generates Pig Latin in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to write a function that takes a string as an argument and prints the string in Pig Latin. (in PigLatin, you move the first letter of the word to the end, and then add "ay". E.g., "this was fun" -> "histay asway unfay".) I am just beginning at R so all I've managed to do is

```
function(x){

    x<-c() str_sub(x, 2, -1) 

....
 }
```

but I really don't know how to move the first letter to the end of the word and add ay. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `gsub("(\\w)(\\w+)", "\\2\\1ay", a)`

Answer (score 2):

One way using base R functions could be to use a combination of `strsplit` and `paste`. We could create a function which acts on a single word

```
f_one = function(word){
  letters = strsplit(word,"")[[1]]
  paste(c(letters[-1],letters[1],"ay"),collapse = "")
}

f_one("this")
## [1] "histay"
```

which splits it into individual letters and then uses paste to stick the first letter to the end and then add "ay".

We could then use a second function which acts on a string of multiple words, splits the string into individual words, applies the function to each individual word and pastes the results back together

```
f_multiple= function(words){
  individual = strsplit(words," ")[[1]]
  paste(sapply(individual,f_one), collapse = " ")
}

f_multiple("this was fun")
## [1] "histay asway unfay"
```

which uses the same logic as the first function but splitting on spaces to give individual words.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex:

```
pl = function(x) {
  x = unlist(strsplit(x, split=" "))
  paste(gsub("(.)(.*)", "\\2\\1ay", x), collapse=" ")
}

pl = Vectorize(pl)

a = c("this was fun", "What is this in pig Latin")

pl(a)
```

> ```
>         this was fun               What is this in pig Latin 
> "histay asway unfay" "hatWay siay histay niay igpay atinLay"
> ```

Comment: I like that `pl` does both single words and sentences in a single function. The icing on the cake is using `Vectorize` although I suspect I could `Vectorize` the `f_multiple` in my answer for the same result. Anyway thought `pl` was neat answer so +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `paste0` to join three strings:

```
#The first character of string x
substr(x,1,1)

#All characters of x except the first
substr(x,2,nchar(a))

# And the string "ay"

pig_latin_x = paste0(substr(x,2,nchar(a)), substr(x,1,1), "ay")
```

This will work on a single word, not a phrase.  For a phrase first separate them with strsplit. The answer from jamieRowen shows you how to achieve this.