# Convert text to Pig Latin in R

Tags: r, regex

What would be a good way for converting text to [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) in R. Here's a solution that I came up with

```
x = "pig"
paste(toupper(substr(x,2,2)), substr(x,3,nchar(x)), tolower(substr(x,1,1)), "ay", sep = "")
#[1] "Igpay"
```

It works for the most part but I have not figured out how to match case of the output with that of the input in an efficient way. Specifically,

- The first letter of output should have same case as the first letter of the input, and
- The subsequent letters should have the same case as the subsequent letters of input

For example,

1. `"mac"` would need to be `"acmay"`
2. `"Mac"` would need to be `"Acmay"`
3. `"McCoy"` would need to be `"CcOymay"`

I may be able to do it with a loop but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: See [How to write function that generates Pig Latin in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579426/how-to-write-function-that-generates-pig-latin-in-r)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks! My biggest problem is matching the case at the beginning and subsequent places.

Comment: I have not studied the topic, but from what I have seen, there is a problem with some consonant clusters at the word start. I doubt the full solution is possible with pure regex. See a [Pig Latin conversion PHP library on GitHub](https://github.com/simplonco/php-pig-latin).

Comment: The y consonant as a vowel might be an issue. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542324/php-pig-latin-y-as-both-vowel-and-consonant/42568860#42568860) if you need to deal with that. That is a pure regex solution and uses a branch reset not available in _R_ but it can be done without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579426/how-to-write-function-that-generates-pig-latin-in-r) in the comments does not account for miXedCase translation. (Frankly, I'm not certain that the OP's intent of carrying the *position* of the upper case is strictly "proper pig-latin". However, if you were to do a quasi-(not-so-)crypt-analysis on the pig-latinized words, having correctly-capitalized letters could be revealing.)

Hard-coding the upper/lower conversion is a bit hard to handle. I think it's best to look specifically at each letter in the source string and translate it to the target. This should handle camelCase (which is not necessarily meaningful in language, but may be appropriate in some context). It needs special handling when dealing with all-caps words.

You will benefit from breaking this into functional components. After a little play (and not trying too hard for efficiency), I suggest these functions:

```
whichUpperL <- function(strings) {
  gr <- gregexpr("[A-Z]", strings)
  mapply(function(g, len) {
    if (any(g < 0)) return(rep(FALSE, len))
    if (length(g) == len) return(rep(TRUE, len))
    ret <- rep(FALSE, len)
    ret[g] <- TRUE
    return(ret)
  }, gr, nchar(strings))
}

toupper2 <- function(st, cond, default = NA) {
  if (length(st) != length(cond)) stop("'st' and 'cond' not the same length")
  mapply(function(s, isupper) {
    lendiff <- max(0, length(s) - length(isupper))
    if (lendiff > 0) {
      if (is.na(default)) default <- all(isupper)
      isupper <- c(isupper, rep(default, lendiff))
    }
    paste(ifelse(isupper, toupper(s), tolower(s)), collapse = "")
  }, strsplit(st, ""), cond)
}

toPig <- function(strings) {
  nchar3 <- (nchar(strings) > 2)
  isupper <- whichUpperL(strings)
  strings[nchar3] <- sapply(strings[nchar3],
                            function(s) paste(substr(s, 2, nchar(s)), substr(s, 1, 1), "ay", sep = ""))
  toupper2(strings, isupper)
}
```

Simple demo of sub-funcs:

```
strings <- c("mac", "Mac", "McCoy", "MCCOY")
str(whichUpperL(strings))
# List of 4
#  $ : logi [1:3] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  $ : logi [1:3] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  $ : logi [1:5] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  $ : logi [1:5] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

toupper2("hello", list(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)))
# [1] "HeLlO"
```

The logic within `toupper2` to handle longer strings is important. Without it, you'll either (a) always lower- or upper-case the `"ay"` at the end, or (b) recycle the `cond` logicals, which will have funny (and frustrating) side-effects. You can't hard-code an extension of 2 due, since not all of pig-latin extends a word by two letters. I default to `NA` so that it can determine based on the presence of even a single lower-case; if `default=TRUE`, then the additional letters are always upper (rarely correct?); if `default=FALSE`, then the letters are always lower (wrong if the entire word is upper); if `default=NA`, the normal behavior here, then it will upper if all other letters are upper.

Given the test strings:

```
toPig(strings)
# [1] "acmay"   "Acmay"   "CcOymay" "CCOYMAY"
```

This just implements the base-case of the pig-latin translation rules. There are [other rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin#Rules) that you'll need to consider, in which case the `substr` logic in `toPig` will need to be modified slightly. Regular expressions might be used (just look for a leading vowel or two leading non-vowels).